# How to get the value of an attached property in code?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a button with a `ToolTipService.ToolTip` in it.
How do I access it in code?

e.g.

```
<Button Name="testButton">
    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
        Test
    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the value of an attached property, use the provided static method:

```
var tooltip = ToolTipService.GetToolTip(testButton);
```

If there is no such static method (not likely, all classes should have static helper methods to get/set attached properties they expose), then use:

```
var tooltip = testButton.GetValue(ToolTipService.ToolTipProperty);
```

Comment: Thanks. Can't accept yet. (BTW, How would I get the `SymbolIcon`, I have that under the button too, but there doesn't seem to be any similar method for that?)

Comment: That's a different process. You can set an x:Name on the SymbolIcon to generate a private field in your class referencing that element, or (if it's the immediate Content of the Button) just `(SymbolIcon)testButton.Content`, or traverse the visual tree manually via [VisualTreeHelper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper.aspx) class.